# Customized data aggregation using vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, aggregate

Could you please help me with the following data aggregation problem?

Here's my initial array:

```
const data = [
    { date: '2023-11-01', type: 'A', casualties: 10, state: 'NY', country: 'USA', site: 'hash1' },
    { date: '2023-11-01', type: 'B', casualties: 5, state: 'NY', country: 'USA', site: 'hash2' },
    { date: '2023-11-02', type: 'A', casualties: 15, state: 'NY', country: 'USA', site: 'hash3' },
    { date: '2023-11-01', type: 'C', casualties: 20, state: 'NY', country: 'USA', site: 'hash4' },
    { date: '2023-11-02', type: 'B', casualties: 8, state: 'NY', country: 'USA', site: 'hash5' },
    { date: '2023-11-03', type: 'A', casualties: 25, state: 'NY', country: 'USA', site: 'hash6' },
    { date: '2023-11-01', type: 'D', casualties: 12, state: 'NY', country: 'USA', site: 'hash7' },
];
```

I would like to aggregate part of the rows under type `other`, depending on the `casualties` value.

If a given `type` has `casualties` equal or higher than a certain threshold for all dates, it should be part of the `results` array.

If a given `type` has `casualties` below the threshold for all dates but it is the only `type` below the threshold, it will be part of the `results` array.

If two or more `types` have `casualties` below a certain threshold for all dates,
they should not be part of the `results` array. For this scenario,
`casualties` will be summed for each date and the `type` value should be `other`.

The `otherCasualties` array should contain all the `types` that have `casualties` below the threshold for all dates.

Examples:

If the `casualtiesThreshold` is `9`, the `results` array should be:

```
results = [
    { date: '2023-11-01', type: 'A', casualties: 10, state: 'NY', country: 'USA' },
    { date: '2023-11-01', type: 'B', casualties: 5, state: 'NY', country: 'USA' },
    { date: '2023-11-02', type: 'A', casualties: 15, state: 'NY', country: 'USA' },
    { date: '2023-11-01', type: 'C', casualties: 20, state: 'NY', country: 'USA' },
    { date: '2023-11-02', type: 'B', casualties: 8, state: 'NY', country: 'USA' },
    { date: '2023-11-03', type: 'A', casualties: 25, state: 'NY', country: 'USA' },
    { date: '2023-11-01', type: 'D', casualties: 12, state: 'NY', country: 'USA' },
];
```

and the `otherCasualties` array should be `[]`.

If the `casualtiesThreshold` is `13`, the `results` array should be:

```
results = [
    { date: '2023-11-01', type: 'A', casualties: 10, state: 'NY', country: 'USA'},
    { date: '2023-11-01', type: 'other', casualties: 17, state: 'NY', country: 'USA' },
    { date: '2023-11-02', type: 'A', casualties: 15, state: 'NY', country: 'USA' },
    { date: '2023-11-01', type: 'C', casualties: 20, state: 'NY', country: 'USA' },
    { date: '2023-11-02', type: 'other', casualties: 8, state: 'NY', country: 'USA' },
    { date: '2023-11-03', type: 'A', casualties: 25, state: 'NY', country: 'USA' },
];
```

and the `otherCasualties` array should be `['B', 'D']`.

This is what I tried:

```
function processCasualties(data, casualtiesThreshold) {
  const results = [];
  const otherCasualties = [];

  const groupedData = data.reduce((acc, item) => {
    const key = item.type;
    if (!acc[key]) {
      acc[key] = [];
    }
    acc[key].push(item);
    return acc;
  }, {});

  const types = Object.keys(groupedData);

  types.forEach(type => {
    const typeData = groupedData[type];
    const totalCasualties = typeData.reduce((acc, item) => acc + item.casualties, 0);
    const allDatesBelowThreshold = typeData.every(item => item.casualties < casualtiesThreshold);

    if (totalCasualties >= casualtiesThreshold || (allDatesBelowThreshold && types.length === 1)) {
      results.push(...typeData.map(item => ({
        date: item.date,
        type: item.type,
        casualties: item.casualties,
        state: item.state,
        country: item.country,
      })));
    } else if (allDatesBelowThreshold) {
      otherCasualties.push(type);
    } else {
      results.push(...typeData.map(item => ({
        date: item.date,
        type: 'other',
        casualties: totalCasualties,
        state: item.state,
        country: item.country,
      })));
    }
  });

  return { results, otherCasualties };
}

const casualtiesThreshold = 13;

const { results, otherCasualties } = processCasualties(data, casualtiesThreshold);

console.log(results);
console.log(otherCasualties);
```

Comment: Hi Nina -- Thank you for your message. The code doesn't work. I'll try to add it to the original question.

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: @user1352042, can you describe, why `'A'` (with smaller casualties) is in the result set for the second result?

Comment: Thank you for your question, @NinaScholz.

 In the second example (```casualtiesThreshold  = 13```), ```A``` is added to the ```results``` array because on 2023-11-02, the associated ```casualties``` (15) is greater than the ```casualtiesThreshold```. ```B``` and ```D``` are not added to the ```results``` array because **all** the associated ```casualties``` are smaller than 13.

Please let me know if I was able to answer your question.

Comment: I've added it to the question, @Thallius.

Comment: Hi @NinaScholz, ```A```-related objects are kept in the ```results``` array as two ```casualties``` values (15 and 25) are bigger than the threshold (13). Given a type ```X```, related objects will be removed from the ```results``` array **only if all** ```casualties``` values are smaller than the ```threshold```.

Comment: that means, if one of same type is greater, then all same types goes to the result. right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take two sets and collect in a first iteration types who match and other type. Then delete the types who match in the `other` set, because this types should be in the result set.

Finally check, if only one type is in the `other` set, then add this type to the result as well.

For all other non matching types take `'other'` as type, grouped by `date`.

```js
const
    fn = (data, threshold) => {
        const
            result = [],
            other = new Set,
            match = new Set,
            others = {};
        
        for (const { type, casualties } of data) [other, match][+(casualties >= threshold)].add(type);
        
        match.forEach(Set.prototype.delete, other);
        
        if (other.size === 1) {
            match.add(...other);
            other.clear();
        }
        
        for (const { date, type, casualties, state, country } of data) {
            if (match.has(type)) {
                result.push({ date, type, casualties, state, country });
                continue;
            }

            if (others[date]) others[date].casualties += casualties;
            else result.push(others[date] = { date, type: 'other', casualties, state, country });
        }

        return { result, otherCasualties: [...other] };
    },
    data = [{ date: '2023-11-01', type: 'A', casualties: 10, state: 'NY', country: 'USA', site: 'hash1' }, { date: '2023-11-01', type: 'B', casualties: 5, state: 'NY', country: 'USA', site: 'hash2' }, { date: '2023-11-02', type: 'A', casualties: 15, state: 'NY', country: 'USA', site: 'hash3' }, { date: '2023-11-01', type: 'C', casualties: 20, state: 'NY', country: 'USA', site: 'hash4' }, { date: '2023-11-02', type: 'B', casualties: 8, state: 'NY', country: 'USA', site: 'hash5' }, { date: '2023-11-03', type: 'A', casualties: 25, state: 'NY', country: 'USA', site: 'hash6' }, { date: '2023-11-01', type: 'D', casualties: 12, state: 'NY', country: 'USA', site: 'hash7' }];
    
console.log(fn(data, 9));
console.log(fn(data, 13));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you for working on the problem! I just needed to remove ```site``` from the for-loop to make the code output mirror the expected results.

Comment: @user1352042, please see edit.