# Aggregating data in JavaScript with two criteria

Tags: javascript, aggregate, data-wrangling

I've been trying to aggregate data so that two criteria are met.

Let's say my initial array (`rawData`) is as follows:

```
rawData = [
  { date: '2023-11-01', fruit: 'oranges', state: 'NY', salePct: 0.10 },
  { date: '2023-11-01', fruit: 'apples', state: 'NY', salePct: 0.25 },
  { date: '2023-11-01', fruit: 'pears', state: 'NY', salePct: 0.10 },
  { date: '2023-11-01', fruit: 'figs', state: 'NY', salePct: 0.01 },
  { date: '2023-11-01', fruit: 'strawberries', state: 'NY', salePct: 0.15 },
  { date: '2023-11-01', fruit: 'raspberries', state: 'NY', salePct: 0.15 },
  { date: '2023-11-01', fruit: 'blueberries', state: 'NY', salePct: 0.15 },
  { date: '2023-11-01', fruit: 'cranberries', state: 'NY', salePct: 0.02 },
  { date: '2023-11-01', fruit: 'pineapples', state: 'NY', salePct: 0.02 },
  { date: '2023-11-01', fruit: 'peaches', state: 'NY', salePct: 0.05 },
  { date: '2023-11-02', fruit: 'oranges', state: 'NY', salePct: 0.20 },
  { date: '2023-11-02', fruit: 'apples', state: 'NY', salePct: 0.20 },
  { date: '2023-11-02', fruit: 'pears', state: 'NY', salePct: 0.10 },
  { date: '2023-11-02', fruit: 'figs', state: 'NY', salePct: 0.10 },
  { date: '2023-11-02', fruit: 'strawberries', state: 'NY', salePct: 0.20 },
  { date: '2023-11-02', fruit: 'raspberries', state: 'NY', salePct: 0.10 },
  { date: '2023-11-02', fruit: 'blueberries', state: 'NY', salePct: 0.03 },
  { date: '2023-11-02', fruit: 'cranberries', state: 'NY', salePct: 0.03 },
  { date: '2023-11-02', fruit: 'pineapples', state: 'NY', salePct: 0.04},
  { date: '2023-11-03', fruit: 'oranges', state: 'NY', salePct: 0.20 },
  { date: '2023-11-03', fruit: 'apples', state: 'NY', salePct: 0.20 },
  { date: '2023-11-03', fruit: 'pears', state: 'NY', salePct: 0.10 },
  { date: '2023-11-03', fruit: 'figs', state: 'NY', salePct: 0.10 },
  { date: '2023-11-03', fruit: 'strawberries', state: 'NY', salePct: 0.30 },
  { date: '2023-11-03', fruit: 'raspberries', state: 'NY', salePct: 0.05 },
  { date: '2023-11-03', fruit: 'blueberries', state: 'NY', salePct: 0.05 },
  { date: '2023-11-05', fruit: 'oranges', state: 'NY', salePct: 0.10 },
  { date: '2023-11-05', fruit: 'apples', state: 'NY', salePct: 0.10 },
  { date: '2023-11-05', fruit: 'pears', state: 'NY', salePct: 0.10 },
  { date: '2023-11-05', fruit: 'figs', state: 'NY', salePct: 0.10 },
  { date: '2023-11-05', fruit: 'strawberries', state: 'NY', salePct: 0.10 },
  { date: '2023-11-05', fruit: 'raspberries', state: 'NY', salePct: 0.25 },
  { date: '2023-11-05', fruit: 'blueberries', state: 'NY', salePct: 0.25 },
];
```

I'd like fruits whose sale percentages for the available dates are below a minimum value for **any of** said dates to be aggregated as `others`.

So, for `minSalePct = 0.10`, the `aggregatedByThreshold` array would be as follows:

```
aggregatedByThreshold = [
  { date: '2023-11-01', fruit: 'oranges', state: 'NY', salePct: 0.10 },
  { date: '2023-11-01', fruit: 'apples', state: 'NY', salePct: 0.25 },
  { date: '2023-11-01', fruit: 'pears', state: 'NY', salePct: 0.10 },
  { date: '2023-11-01', fruit: 'strawberries', state: 'NY', salePct: 0.15 },
  { dat3: '2023-11-01', fruit: 'others', state: 'NY', salePct: 0.40},
  { date: '2023-11-02', fruit: 'oranges', state: 'NY', salePct: 0.20 },
  { date: '2023-11-02', fruit: 'apples', state: 'NY', salePct: 0.20 },
  { date: '2023-11-02', fruit: 'pears', state: 'NY', salePct: 0.10 },
  { date: '2023-11-02', fruit: 'strawberries', state: 'NY', salePct: 0.20 },
  { date: '2023-11-02', fruit: 'others', state: 'NY', salePct: 0.30 },
  { date: '2023-11-03', fruit: 'oranges', state: 'NY', salePct: 0.20 },
  { date: '2023-11-03', fruit: 'apples', state: 'NY', salePct: 0.20 },
  { date: '2023-11-03', fruit: 'pears', state: 'NY', salePct: 0.10 },
  { date: '2023-11-03', fruit: 'strawberries', state: 'NY', salePct: 0.30 },
  { date: '2023-11-03', fruit: 'others', state: 'NY', salePct: 0.10 },
  { date: '2023-11-05', fruit: 'oranges', state: 'NY', salePct: 0.10 },
  { date: '2023-11-05', fruit: 'apples', state: 'NY', salePct: 0.10 },
  { date: '2023-11-05', fruit: 'pears', state: 'NY', salePct: 0.10 },
  { date: '2023-11-05', fruit: 'strawberries', state: 'NY', salePct: 0.10 },
  { date: '2023-11-05', fruit: 'others', state: 'NY', salePct: 0.50 },
];
```

However, there's a maximum number of non-aggregated fruit (`maxFruit`) to be enforced as well. Fruits whose sum of sales percentages across dates are low are progressively added to `others` until `maxFruit` is met. If `maxFruit = 3`, the `aggregatedByThresholdAndQuantity` array would be as follows:

```
aggregatedByThresholdAndQuantity = [
  { date: '2023-11-01', fruit: 'oranges', state: 'NY', salePct: 0.10 },
  { date: '2023-11-01', fruit: 'apples', state: 'NY', salePct: 0.25 },
  { date: '2023-11-01', fruit: 'strawberries', state: 'NY', salePct: 0.15 },
  { dat3: '2023-11-01', fruit: 'others', state: 'NY', salePct: 0.50},
  { date: '2023-11-02', fruit: 'oranges', state: 'NY', salePct: 0.20 },
  { date: '2023-11-02', fruit: 'apples', state: 'NY', salePct: 0.20 },
  { date: '2023-11-02', fruit: 'strawberries', state: 'NY', salePct: 0.20 },
  { date: '2023-11-02', fruit: 'others', state: 'NY', salePct: 0.40 },
  { date: '2023-11-03', fruit: 'oranges', state: 'NY', salePct: 0.20 },
  { date: '2023-11-03', fruit: 'apples', state: 'NY', salePct: 0.20 },
  { date: '2023-11-03', fruit: 'strawberries', state: 'NY', salePct: 0.30 },
  { date: '2023-11-03', fruit: 'others', state: 'NY', salePct: 0.30 },
  { date: '2023-11-05', fruit: 'oranges', state: 'NY', salePct: 0.10 },
  { date: '2023-11-05', fruit: 'apples', state: 'NY', salePct: 0.10 },
  { date: '2023-11-05', fruit: 'strawberries', state: 'NY', salePct: 0.10 },
  { date: '2023-11-05', fruit: 'others', state: 'NY', salePct: 0.70 },
];
```

Additionally, I'd like to have an array with the names of the fruits that were aggregated as others:

```
otherFruit = ['pears', 'figs', 'raspberries', 'cranberries', 'blueberries', 'pineapples', 'peaches'];
```

These solutions solve part of the problem but I wasn't able to combine them to
generate the desired output:

- [customized-data-aggregation-using-vanilla-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77440235/customized-data-aggregation-using-vanilla-javascript)
- [aggregating-data-using-vanilla-javascript-or-another-javascript-library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77608219/aggregating-data-using-vanilla-javascript-or-another-javascript-library-e-g-l/77608856#77608856)

Even though I used two arrays to explain the scenario (`aggregatedByThreshold` and `aggregatedByThresholdAndQuantity`), the solution does not need intermediate steps. `aggregatedByThresholdAndQuantity` and `otherFruit`, and the possibility of setting the two criteria (`minSalePct` and `maxFruit`) would be enough. I am also okay with solutions that employ other libraries such as lodash.

Comment: Where are you running into problems? You didn't include your attempt.

Comment: @mykaf [Problem-solving effort is not required in questions if the problem is well-scoped](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260909).

Comment: This question is also part of [a discussion on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/427510).

Comment: What defines the order of the fruits in the result lists? Just the order in the source array, or is there some other defined order?

Comment: Why aren't there any `blueberries` in any of the aggregated arrays? They have several entries above `minSalePct `, so aren't "below a minimum value for *all* the available dates". In fact they have the second-highest `salePct` for several days, so I would expect them to also survive the `maxFruit` criteria at least on some dates.

Comment: @zcoop98 Fruits will be added to `aggregatedByThreshold` as individual records if their respective`salePct`s are at least equal to `minSalePct` for all available dates.  Otherwise, fruits will be grouped as `others`. For instance, `figs` individual records were not kept as its `salePct` was below `minSalePct` on `2023-11-01`.

There's no order for the fruits in the arrays. 

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi: I fixed the question. Thank you for flagging. If **any** of the individual records of a given fruit is below `minSalePct`, the said fruit will be grouped as `others`.

Comment: FYI: questions should contain only one question, if there are multiple they become susceptible to being closed as needing more focused. I would remove the "additional, I'd like to have" follow up question. If you ever receive an answer and that answer does not provide you the guidance to figure out any additional requirements on your own, you can always post a second question.